# Found regex patterns prints out memory location

Tags: python, regex

I'm using regex to search through a book text file for number a number in the trillions in this format {n,nn,nnn},nnn,nnn,nnn,nnn. I think my regex pattern works but when I print out my list of captured strings they are designated as memory locations <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fd48e11f510>. How do I get the object in the list and not the location. Here is my code. Thanks.

```
 import re
 text='/users/user/resources/text'
 items=[]
 with open(text,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
            item=re.search(r'\d*,', line)
            items.append(item)
 print(items)
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/regex.html#performing-matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call .group() on the match objects from items.

Check out the Match class http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html.

The items list contains Match instances, which convert to the string representation you see when printed.

Something like:

```
print([item.group() for item in items])
```

Is what you want.